# TYPO3 - Extension ke_search - Bug in scheduler

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x

I'm using :

- TYPO3 6.2
- ke_search 2.2

Everything work fine except the indexing process, I mean :

- If I manually index (with the backend module) it's OK, no error messages.
- If I run manually the scheduler indexing task it's OK, no error messages.
- If I run the scheduler with the `php typo3/cli_dispatch.phpsh scheduler` command, then I got this error :

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 16777216 bytes exhausted (tried to
>   allocate 87 bytes) in
>   /path_to_my_website/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Cache/Frontend/VariableFrontend.php on line 99

For your information :

- my PHP `memory_limit` setting is on `128M`.
- Other tasks are OK.
- After this error appears on my console, the scheduler task is locked :

[image]

I can't figure out what's wrong ?

EDIT : I made flush frontend caches + flush general caches + flush system caches. If I run one more time the scheduler via the console, this is the new error I get :

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 16777216 bytes exhausted (tried to
>   allocate 12288 bytes) in
>   /path_to_my_website/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Database/QueryGenerator.php
>   on line 1265

EDIT 2 : if I disable all my indexer configurations, all goes well. But if I enable even 1 configuration -> PHP error.

Here is one of the indexer file : [image]

Comment: can you provide your indexer configurations?

Comment: @MarcelWasilewski done :)

Comment: Ok, I tried to debug and the issue is in the "class.tx_kesearch_indexer.php" file, line : "$searchObj = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance('tx_kesearch_indexer_types_' . $this->indexerConfig['type'], $this);". The makeInstance() doesn't works ... but "tx_kesearch_indexer_types_page" is correct. I don't get it.